# "group descriptors corrupted" after resize of partition was interrupted. How to fix it in a short time

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, disk, syslinux

I was running a resize of an ext4 partition, using gparted.
Accidentally it was interrupted because the system restarted.
Since that moment I cannot mount my partition anymore, `dmesg|grep sda` says `group descriptors corrupted`.

I was trying to solve it with gparted, but it was taking quite a long time (more than 8 h).
So I killed e2fsck and gparted, to find another solution, did not find it.

Do you have any suggestion to fix the partition possibly in a short time?

Answer (score 0):

**Never ever stop a resize or an `e2fsck`!**

If your files are *not all lost by now*, let the `e2fsck` finish!

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...  :-(